# How Do I Get Image Src Attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I found a lot of questions like this but none of them are helpful

The problem is when I try `console.log(document.getElementById("image").getAttribute("src"))`
it just return `null`

how do actually get image src attribute?

**HTML code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Endless Discuss</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body class="dark-theme">
    <button class="theme" onclick="change_theme()"><img src="theme/Dark.png" class="logo" id="image"></button>
    <textarea class="input-post" id="comment-content" placeholder="Type message here..." onkeypress="enter(event)"></textarea><br>
    <button class="submit" id="submit_button" onclick="post_comment()">Send</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("image").src` should do

Comment: Please provide your html markup too.

Comment: Assuming your code is executed from "script.js" you should have "theme/Dark.png"  output in the console. --> Your code is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `src` attribute of `getElementById()` method result.

```
console.log(document.getElementById("image").src);
```

Comment: The `.src` IDL attribute is [reflected](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-dom-interfaces.html#reflect) at the attribute level. If they had an `.src` value from there, they would also have an `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in your JS code

```
var youtubeimgsrc = document.getElementById("ImageTagId").src;
```

I have coded up a simple get image source sample code. You may have a look at it

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myImg").src;;
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/aquir/aquir1311/aquir131100316/23569861-sample-grunge-red-round-stamp.jpg" width="107" height="98">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me to get image source</button>
<p id="label"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

use Jquery: $("#image").attr('src');